# How to access and control a checkbox that's inside a style?

Tags: delphi, styles, firemonkey

I have a style for list box items which contains a checkbox. For every list box item, there is a property called *isChecked* that I can read and write to just fine, but it does not influence the checkbox in the style. Any idea how to make the checkbox synchronize with the *isChecked* property?

Here's the style structure:

[image: Style structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out list box contains a boolean property named "ShowCheckboxes"...

[image]